# How to compute vector transformations on the CPU?

Tags: c++, directx

[enter image description here][1]

I’ve been trying to transform my vertices outside the main graphics pipeline. I need them on the CPU. But as simple as it seemed at first, I have spent a significant duration trying to implement that but simply failed. I have been trying to figure out the error with my method, but it just seems perfect to me.

I have my world, camera and projection matrices (that I am using in the main graphics pipeline to render objects) working. I use the same matrices to transform the vectors with the function **XMVector4Transform()**. I have set the w component of my vector to 1  and then when I transform my vertices, instead of getting normalized (between -1 to 1) outputs (while the 3d model is inside the screen space), I am getting values that are outside the screen while with the same matrix transformations in the shader, it is being rendered inside the screen space.

Now after some digging I found that I need to use the function `XMVector4Normalize()` to normalize the coords. Though after using that the results were normalized, but still there is a major offset between the CPU computed vertices and those that I compute in the shader. And the offset margin increases as I move the objects to the edges.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhnpB.png
in the above screenshot, the wireframe is rendered using the CPU computed vertices and the solidly shaded version is being rendered in the main pipeline. the offset that i mentioned can be clearly observed in the screenshot.

PS : I am rendering the CPU computed verts just to test...

```cpp
    DirectX::XMVECTOR v1;
    v1.m128_f32[0] = pMesh[i].GetVertices()[j].x;
    v1.m128_f32[1] = pMesh[i].GetVertices()[j].y;
    v1.m128_f32[2] = pMesh[i].GetVertices()[j].z;
    v1.m128_f32[3] = 1.f;


    projectedVectors[i].verts.emplace_back(XMVECTOR());
    v1 = XMVector4Transform(XMVector4Transform(v1, *mView), *mProj);;

    v1 = XMVector4Normalize(v1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result you get from this transform is in so-called clip space. This is an artificial 4D-space, where the `w`-component denotes the common denominator for all other components. Therefore, instead of normalizing, you want to divide by `w` (so-called *perspective divide*).

Btw, instead of assigning the components of the vector to the registers yourself, you could also use `XMLoadFloat4()`. This would take care of everything taking into account what is available.

Comment: You are welcome. If an answer solved your question, please accept it by clicking the check-mark next to it. This also applies to your other question.